# Get post shares MySql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a problem when i'm trying to get posts shares.

First i have a table named : Wa_Posts {id,user_id... etc}

Second table named : Wa_Shares {id,post_id,user_id} .

and for sure Wa_Posts.id = Wa_Shares.post_id

my question is how can get shared posts with all posts ?

My query is:

> SELECT `id` FROM `Wa_Posts` AS post1 WHERE `id` >0 OR `id` IN (SELECT `post_id` FROM `Wa_Sares` WHERE `user_id` = USER_ID) ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5

Thank you, and waiting for your help guys !

Comment: do you mean the count of all shares by all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to get all shares. Something similar to (untested):

`SELECT 
  wa_shares.id share_id,
  wa_posts.id post_id,
  wa_posts.user_id user_id
FROM 
  wa_shares 
LEFT JOIN 
  wa_posts 
    ON wa_posts.id = wa_shares.post_id"
ORDER BY
  wa_posts.id DESC
LIMIT 5`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it helped me to solve the problem, and it has been solved .